# How to pass a secondary generic parameter to a generic class constructor without a second declare type

Tags: c#, generics

It is the first time i have gotten this requirement and i can't figure out how to make it work.
I have a class that has a generic type. Then the constructor need to get an object of that type. So far so good. Now that same constructor need to receive a secondary generic type as a parameter of that constructor without having to define a second generic type in the class. So here some sample code simplified for understanding purpose

```
// a base class
public class Item {}

// one of many derived class
public class Switch : Item {}

// another class but unrelated to item
public class Sheet {}

// a derived of sheet
public class CoinSheet : Sheet {}
```

Now i need a generic class that has an Item as a type so a basic class would be the following and it works perfectly

```
public class Manager<T> where T : Item
{
    public T RelatedItem { get; set; } = null;
    
    public Manager(T relatedItem)
    {
        RelatedItem = relatedItem;
    }
}
```

The problem is that i now need to pass an object of type `Sheet` to the constructor without specifing it in the generic of the class. The following does NOT work but it's that i mean by that (based on the previous class definition

```
public class Manager<T> where T : Item
{
    public T RelatedItem { get; set; } = null;
    
    public Manager(T relatedItem, T2 relatedSheet) where T2 : Sheet
    {
        RelatedItem = relatedItem;
        InstanceGenerator.Create<T2>(relatedSheet);
    }
}
```

I proposed to call a method within the `Manager` class instead that can have the secondary generic type without altering the `Manager` class definition (which cannot change) but i was given a definitive no as an answer.

I know i can just change the parameter type of that second parameter to `object` and forget about generic  and just hardcode the check for if the `object` is of type `Sheet` and find by reflection the `InstanceGenerator.Create` and invoke it but if it's avoidable i rather do so.

Comment: If the second argument must be a `Sheet`, does it have to be generic or can it just be `Sheet`?

Comment: @ScottHannen I do need a generic for the secondary method to be called. If i hardcode `InstanceGenerator.Create<Sheet>(relatedSheet);` the method doesn't work. I need the actual type as it has different behaviors. Hence the part where i said i could pass an object and by reflection find the correct generic method matching the type passed. The advantage of generics is that i can call another generic directly and the type enforce is applied as well.

Comment: What prevents adding the second generic argument to the class? `public class Manager<T, T2>` and constraining `T2` to be `Sheet`?

Comment: Can't you create.a generic factory method instead of using the constructor?

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea If you do that you still have to know the type, which is what the generic constraint is perfectly suited for.

Comment: Yes,, fully agree, but the constraint might be placed on the method, and the factory method can be evolved into a factory class. It can be argued that T2 at class level is more explicit about the 'link'.

Comment: It's not clear what  your wanting to do with the result of InstanceGenerator.Create, but you could add a static method to `Manager<T>` to create the instance and the `InstanceGenerator` call. Something like `public static (Manager<T>,T2) CreateWithRelatedSheet<T2>(T relatedItem, T2 relatedSheet) where T2: Sheet => (new Manager<T>(relatedItem), InstanceGenerator.Create(relatedSheet));`  assuming `InstanceGenerator<T2>.Create` returns an instance of T2.

Comment: @ScottHannen The requirement are to not add a secondary generic to the `Manager` class. so only `Manager<T>` is allowed in this contract.

Comment: @asawyer what `InstanceGenerator` does is out of the scope here. There is hundreds of little things i have removed for simplicity reasons. The question is about is there a easier format with generic allowing this or do i have to go with reflection and call all different bit of the software generic method with it.

Comment: If you don't need the result of the `InstanceGenerator` call just change the result of the example from a tuple to `Manager<T>` and add a message body that calls `InstanceGenerator` and returns the new `Manager<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't add it to the class, you can't add it to the constructor.

```
public class Manager<T> where T : Item
{
    public T RelatedItem { get; set; } = null;
    // THIS IS INVALID
    public Manager<T2>(T relatedItem, T2 relatedSheet) where T2 : Sheet
    {
        RelatedItem = relatedItem;
        InstanceGenerator.Create<T2>(relatedSheet);
    }
}
```

Which makes sense. The constructor will only be called once, so there is no point changing the T2 in the constructor if it is to affect the method.

Your two real options are

1. Direct use of Sheet.

```
public class Manager<T> where T : Item
{
    public T RelatedItem { get; set; } = null;
    
    public Manager(T relatedItem, Sheet relatedSheet)
    {
        RelatedItem = relatedItem;
        InstanceGenerator.Create<T2>(relatedSheet);
    }
}
```

2. The T2 to be added on class level.

Comment: That's what i was afraid i could avoid. But if that really impossible i don't have a choice to pass the object normally and use reflection for all the sub calls. Thanks for the sanity check.